# Characterizing convex hull by set of affinely independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, simplex, convex-hulls

While the statement seems intuitively plausible, I am currently struggling to see a proof that any convex hull "spanned" by a set of $n+1$ affinely independent $n$-vectors, $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1}\}$, is uniquely characterized by this set of vectors.

That is to say, how can I see that $$\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\lambda_j\,x_j:\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\lambda_j=1\text{ and }\lambda_j\geq0\,\,\forall\,\,j\right\}=\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\gamma_j\,z_j:\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\gamma_j=1\text{ and }\gamma_j\geq0\,\,\forall\,\,j\right\}$$implies that $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1}\}=\{z_1,z_2,...,z_{k+1}\}.$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your  set of $n+1$ vectors is the set of extreme points of their convex hull.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. I can see that my set of vectors correspond to the vertices of a, say, triangular region in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, it would seem entirely obvious. Maybe, I am at a loss here. But it is not obvious to me, how the fact that I can write the "spanning" vectors as a convex combination  with $\lambda$ beeing a vertex of the $\Delta_n$ simplex implies that $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1}\}=\{z_1,z_2,...,z_{k+1}\}.$ May I ask you to elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @YL-Wint the convex hull is exactly that simplex $\Delta_n$. Thus, if the two sets have the same convex hull, they are equal, since they are the vertex of the same simplex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use now use the barycentric coordinates associated with the simplex $\Delta$. For simplicity, let us write $s_j,t_j$ instead of $x_j-O,z_j-O$ for the vectors. Note that, thanks to the affine linear independence of the two sets, these new sets of vectors are linearly independent.

Since the two set have the same convex hull we already know that every element of one set can be written as a linear combination of elements from the other. Thus our problem is reduced to prove that such a linear combination consists of only one vector.

As a proof by contradiction, let
$$t_l=\sum \lambda_j s_j \\
\exists_{p\neq q}\lambda_p,\lambda_q≠0$$

This implies (together with the fact that the two set have the same convex hull)
$$s_p=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\gamma_jt_j\ (1)
\\
s_q=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\hat{\gamma}_jt_j\ (2)$$
Combining with the precedent requirement, we get

$$s_l=\lambda_p\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\gamma_js_j+\lambda_q\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\hat{\gamma}_js_j+...$$

By linear independence (and the fact that $\lambda\ge 0$) we obtain

$$\gamma_{j\neq l}=0\\ \hat{\gamma}_{j\neq l}=0$$

This yeld (thanks to (1),(2) )

$$s_p=\gamma_l t_l\\
s_q=\hat{\gamma}_l t_l$$

This contradicts the linear independence of $s_p, s_q$.